# Inconsistent output when using foreach on a partitioned RDD in Apache Spark: should it be avoided?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, foreach, action

The foreach action on a partitioned RDD yields unpredictable results. Why does this happen?

For instance, I attempted to print doubled values using the foreach action on an RDD partitioned into two slices (numSlices=2). Here is the code:

```py
numbers = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], numSlices=2)
print(numbers.collect())

def f(x):
    print(x, x*2)
    
numbers.foreach(lambda x: f(x))
```

However, the output is inconsistent. Sometimes it correctly displays the pairs consisting of the original value ***x*** and
***2x***. But when I rerun the code, the output differs, as shown below. Should I avoid using foreach when working with partitioned RDDs?

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
15  102

62  124

73  146

84  168

9 18
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Spark is a parallel computing engine. It does not process partitions sequentially but in parallel.

`print(x, x*2)` basically does the following actions sequentially: `print(x)`, `print(' ')`, `print(x*2)`, `print(\n)`. Now, let's analyze the first line of your result. Let's consider that `1` and `5` are in distinct partitions. If they are processed in parallel by two separate executors, the following sequence of actions could happen:

```py
print(1) # executor_1
print(5) # executor_2
print(' ') # executor_1
print(' ') # executor_2
print(5*2) # executor_2
print(1*2) # executor_1
print(\n) # executor_2
print(\n) # executor_1
```

For both executors, the sequence of action is coherent but since the two sequences are entangled, it yields the strange output you witness:

```
15  102
```

Notice that if you force spark to handle everything on the same core, the output becomes more coherent:

```py
>>> numbers.coalesce(1).foreach(lambda x: f(x))
1 2
2 4
3 6
4 8
5 10
6 12
7 14
8 16
9 18
10 20
```

Comment: Finally, I got it. Thank you very much.